# При подключении зависимостей через npm отключается интернет

Tags: npm

При подключении зависимостей через npm отключается интернет полностью в VS Code.

Есть проект, я его склонировал, прописываю `npm i` и начинается загрузка. И в какой-то момент загрузка останавливается, отключается интернет полностью. То есть даже на телефоне подключенном по вайфай интернет отрубается.

Перезагружать пробовал, не помогает.

Вот сама ошибка:

`npm i`

```
npm ERR! code ECONNRESET
npm ERR! syscall read
npm ERR! errno -4077
npm ERR! network read ECONNRESET
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
```

Comment: Ну хорошо, а что если сымитировать высокую нагрузку на сеть в плане отправляемых и принимаемых данных? Интернет тоже отвалится? Что если попытаться установить 1 пакет из npm, а не 50?

Comment: у меня устанавливается несколько пакетов, и на одном из них все перестает работать

Comment: можете дополнить вопрос ссылкой на проект, который вы клонировали?